# How to transform a rectangle into a circle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, geometry

I want to turn a rectangular image into a circle using the HTMLCanvas element. (Finally I only need the upper half of the circle but that could be easily managed by cutting the resulting circle in half.)

From this

[image: Rectangle]

To this

[image: Circle]

My idea was to do a simple line by line transformation. So far I have just the basic drawing logic but I'm totally lost with the math for the transformation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function init() {
    var img = this;
    var imgH = img.height;
    var imgW = img.width;

    // make the canvas the same size as the image.
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    c.width = imgW;
    c.height = imgH;

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var halfHeight = imgH/2;

    // draw the upper part
    // line by line
    for(var i = 0; i < halfHeight; i++) {
        // I'm totally lost here.

        // current output without transformation
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, i, imgW, 1, 0, i, imgW, 1);
    }

    // add the second half which must not be transformed
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, halfHeight, imgW, halfHeight, 0, halfHeight, imgW, halfHeight);
};
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/52TjZ.png";

</script>
</html>
```

A fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kirschkern/amq7t6ru/2/

(I need it in pure JS and 2d. No three.js, no webgl.)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Turn each line in to a cubic bezier curve using `context.cubicBezierTo` and move the top endpoint of each line (now cubic bezier curve) to the top endpoint of the middle line. [Here](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67) is a playground to learn about cubic bezier curves.

Comment: @markE thanks for your answer. While this looks promising at first, I don't really get it. To me the bezierCurveTo is a drawing method. My rectangular data is finally an image. The line images I provided here are just to make it clear. I will not draw simple lines on the canvas. I want to transform pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about Javascript but as this seems more of a mathematical question, I'll have my shot.

Replace the lines

```
    // I'm totally lost here.

    // current output without transformation
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, i, imgW, 1, 0, i, imgW, 1);
```

with

```
    var xMargin = -Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow((i-halfHeight)/halfHeight,2))*imgW/2+imgW/2;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, i, imgW, 1, xMargin, i, imgW-(2*xMargin), 1);
```

This distorts the upper half of the image as an ellipse (a circle would work only if your input image would be a square) as this:

[image: Image with the upper half distorted]

Does this solve your question?

## Explanation

I took the equation of a shifted ellipse from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation_of_a_shifted_ellipse) and set *c1* and *a* to be equal to `imgW/2` and *c2* and *b* to *imgH/2*. Taking `i` for *y* let me compute *x*; I saved one of the solutions as `xMargin`. The width of the picture at the given vertical coordinate would be the original width minus twice the margin.

In the end, I fed `drawImage()` with these inputs, see the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp).

Comment: Man, you really rocked my day! This looks great, is absolutely enough for what I need it for and I understand it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Plain 2D JavaScript does not have primitives to distort images like this. So a simple `drawImage` will not be enough.

What you can do is approximate things. Write a function which for every point in the distorted image (the one with the circle) computes the corresponding position in the original image. Then you can do one of four things, in increasing order of effort and resulting quality.

1. Iterate over all the pixels in the destination image, and look up the corresponding pixel value in the source image.
2. Like before, but with subsampling: take several positions inside the square of the source pixel, and average the resuling colors for a smoother appearance.
3. Approximate the affine transformation in a given point (for this you will likely need partial derivatives of your mapping function) and use it to draw an affinely transformed image.
4. Same as 3 but with projective instead of affine transforms. That would arguably make it 3D in its formulation.
5. Like 1 or 2 but implement all of that in WebGL as a fragment shader. I know you said you don't want that, but in terms of performance and resulting quality this should give the best results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer and the different possibilities. While I'm pretty lost in the mathematical and webgl area the solution from Dominik Mokriš works for me and his example makes it easy to get it.